# Magento 2 : require default js on cart

Tags: magento2, php

I'm trying to add a product from cart page through ajax, I need to require the default JS : `'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'` so that I can update the cart totals.
But as soon as I place this code on my page :

```
<script>
    require([
'jquery',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data', 
'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals'],
function($, customerData, getTotals) {
   //MY LOGIC
}
</script>
```

I'm getting the error :

```
Cannot read property 'sectionLoadUrl' of undefined
```

Is there any way to fix this ? I tried to use 'domReady!' but it's not working.